# Real example on working Django user/auth system

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I have been learning django pretty quickly, yet have stumbled a little bit on how to make and deploy a registration system that works with auth. I have read the tutorial on djangobook (yes I know it's 'outdated') but the style of writing seems a bit all over the place, and it doesn't really give me a concrete working example to look at.

That being the case, I am looking for a concrete example (one that can be deployed on a serious user heavy website). If anyone has any good tutorials and or examples to share, I would love the extra help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to build a registration system, there is actually no need. Here is something that already works - 
https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/

It has good documentation as well and is pretty easy to set up.

Comment: Thank you, this makes life easy ;)

Comment: Is this what people usually use as a standard?

Comment: Yes, Django and Python are really based on DRY principles (Don't repeat yourself ;)). These are open source and widely used apps.